# How to dump whole MySQL contents from PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a clean way (no hardcoding) in which I can dump all the contents of a database directly to HTML using PHP?

I don't want to run queries for every table and step through the results, outputting them. I need this for testing purposes, so the tables aren't that big.

Any hints?

I want this done directly in my php file, where the rest of the test takes place, so that I may compare with the sample. I need to do this automatically, so can't really use tools like PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: Or [Adminer](http://www.adminer.org) :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this ought to work:

```
<?php

function dump_mysql_results($mysql_table){
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `$table` WHERE 1",[your connection]) or die(mysql_error());
    if (!mysql_num_rows($query)){die("No rows in $table");}
    while($r=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        if (!isset($html)){
            $keys = array_keys($r); 
            $html = "<tr>";
            foreach($keys as $key){
                $html .= "<th>$key</th>";
            }
            $html .= "</tr>";
        }
        $html .= "<tr>";
        foreach($r as $value){
            $html .= "<td>$value</td>";
        }
        $html .= "</tr>";   
    }
    return "<table>".$html."</table>";
}
```

//ADDING a loop to dump the whole db:

```
$tables = mysql_list_tables ( 'database name',$link_identifier) or die(mysql_error());
while($r=mysql_fetch_array($tables)){
    echo dump_mysql_results($r[0]);
}

?>
```

Comment: use this function and write a loop based on the results of a mysql_list_tables function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-tables.php... I've modified my answer slightly to show this.

Comment: I used this, since I can't find a more elegant way of doing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use SHOW TABLES to get the list of tables, then iterate through them normally to select all the rows and display in HTML.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-tables.html

Answer (score 0):

What about [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) ?

```
<?php
 exec('mysqldump --user=DBuser --password=DBpass --host=localhost --compact --xml DBname > file.xml');
?>
```

Then use  [`simpleXML`](http://id.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) to convert xml to HTML